# Adding zoneId in mocean advertising in WebWorks

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry-10

I created a mobile app using HTML5 and WebWorks and am trying to insert an advertisement banner. I'm following the guide found in the [WebWorks Community Samples README](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Community-Samples/blob/master/advertising/README.md).

But I don't really exactly where to put the zoneId on the JavaScript file.

Can someone tell me exactly where and how do I put the zoneId?